# MariaDB and flyway syntax error but not in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, command-line-interface, flyway

I'm trying to execute (migrate) SQL scripts (MariaDB flavour).
I am using Flyway in order to run the scripts. However, some scripts fail...

**The script which fails:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_cool_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_db
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT;
    SET n = (SELECT COUNT(uuid) FROM my_db WHERE uuid != NEW.uuid AND a_uuid = NEW.a_uuid AND number = NEW.number AND event_id IS NULL AND t_begin < NEW.t_end AND t_end > NEW.t_begin);
    IF n > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Oof. ERROR!!!';
    END IF;
END;
```

**Error message:**

> *Migration cool_script.sql failed
>   ------------------------------------------------------ SQL State  : 42000 Error Code : 1064 Message    : (conn=2661) You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6*

When I try to execute the same scripts thru Java (they are run as Prepared Statements, sent over JDBC to MariaDB) everything goes as planned without any errors.

**Java:**

```
connection.prepareStatement(sql).execute();
```

I can really not explain to myself why that is happening.

Comment: What you mean by *execute the same scripts thru Java *? Flyway is also Java.

Comment: they are being run as Prepared Statements

Comment: What "they"? What exactly is the content of prepared statement?

Comment: they = the statements contained in the scripts.

Comment: Show your Java code.

Comment: `connection.prepareStatement(sql).execute();`

Comment: If you don't show the code, it is hard to help you.

Comment: Update: I have tried executing the failing SQL in a flyway repeat-script (R prefixed) and changed CREATE TRIGGER to CREATE OR REPLACE trigger. As excpected that didn't work either...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem lies within not using delimiters.
In order for the statements to parse successfully delimiters should be used as following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_cool_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_db
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT;
    SET n = (SELECT COUNT(uuid) FROM my_db WHERE uuid != NEW.uuid AND a_uuid = NEW.a_uuid AND number = NEW.number AND event_id IS NULL AND t_begin < NEW.t_end AND t_end > NEW.t_begin);
    IF n > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Oof. ERROR!!!';
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The reason why it worked in Java was that the Java prepareStatement seems to add custom delimiters or something else...